# Meteor lepozepo:s3 - Reference Error S3 is not defined

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use `lepozepo:s3` for a new project.

On the client this seems to work fine:

```
console.log(S3);
S3.config = {
  key: Meteor.settings.private.awsS3.access_key,
  secret: Meteor.settings.private.awsS3.secret,
  bucket: Meteor.settings.private.awsS3.bucket,
  region: Meteor.settings.private.awsS3.region,
}
console.log(S3);
```

This shows clearly hat the S3 object is defined before the call to the configuration and then later updated.

On the client, however, I am getting a reference error when trying to implement the upload function or helper as per the documentation.

```
Template.upload.helpers({
  "files": function () {
    console.log(S3);
    return S3.collection.find();
  }
})
```

I'm not doing any imports but have tried before to `import S3 from "meteor/lepozepo:s3"` and S3 ended up being `{}` and empty object.

Comment: have you got any solution for this